# How to get an Authorization Code from UIPath

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, authorization, httprequest, uipath-orchestrator

I am trying to start a robot in my UIpath-orchestrator via Google Appscript.
I have already implemented everything into my script from this documentation:

https://dev.joget.org/community/display/KBv6/Integration+with+UiPath+Robotic+Process+Automation#IntegrationwithUiPathRoboticProcessAutomation-1.GetAccessandIDTokens

But I am actually facing a problem:
Like described in 1.2 of the documentation, I need the authorization code for generating a refresh token. Since I want to write a script to obtain this automatically, the described way with pasting the URL into the browser manually with the code challenge (which btw works fine in my case) is not the way to go for me, as you probably can imagine.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this? I would also be fine, if you have a working Postman- or curl-approach - it wouldn’t be a problem to transform this then by myself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of curl you can use [Apps Script's UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: I know how to use the UrlFetchApp. As mentioned, the implementation into appscript syntax is not my problem :) - I actually don't know how to do the request itself since I am facing problems for example with the login and the correct redirect...

Comment: Well if you need oauth implementation then they have library for that, if you have issue with your own implementation, post your code here and someone may help you

Answer (score -1):

This will be deprecated anyway... :(
Actually what I have to try now is to set up an external application, which I did. I also created an access token like this:

```
function getAccessToken() {
  var data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': '****',
    'client_secret': '*****',
    'scope': 'OR.Machines'
  };

  var header = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cloud.uipath.com/identity_/connect/token", header);
  Logger.log(response);
  var messageContent = response.getContentText();
  var result = JSON.parse(messageContent);
  var access_token = result['access_token'];
  return access_token;
}
```

Now what I try to do now is to get a process Release Key with whom I can start the job then...
For testing reasons, I tried it with curl:
curl -H  "accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "X-UIPATH-TenantName: [tenantName]" -H "X-UIPATH-OrganizationUnitId: default" --insecure -v [https://cloud.uipath.com/[organization]/[TenantName]/odata/Releases?$filter=ProcessKey"](https://cloud.uipath.com/%5Borganization%5D/%5BTenantName%5D/odata/Releases?$filter=ProcessKey%22) -H "Authorization: Bearer [accesstoken]"
Actually what I see in the return is a 400 Bad request...
What have I done wrong?

Comment: you have to ask a new question under the right tag to get answers quickly. this is not the correct place to wait for answers.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.